# Netty fastCGI codec

Tags: java, netty, fastcgi, codec

Do we have some codec for [FastCGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) messages from ngnix or lighthttpd?

If no what are the most close codecs for this purpose?

May be there is a way to configure [jFastCGI](http://www.jfastcgi.org) for request handling via Netty?

All I want to do is to replace php app behind ngnix without reconfiguring anything. Just shut down fastCGI php server and turn up netty one.